# Link inside Magnific Popup modal not working

Tags: javascript, html, magnific-popup

I have a very simple magnific popup modal, which has a link inside it. When the link is clicked though, the URL isn't loaded and the only way to continue is to close the modal.  Here's my code to initiate the popup:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {
    $('.popup-content').magnificPopup({
            type: 'inline',
            fixedContentPos: true,
            fixedBgPos: true,
            overflowY: 'scroll',
            closeBtnInside: true,
            preloader: false,
            callbacks: {
                beforeOpen: function() {
                this.st.mainClass = this.st.el.attr('data-effect');
                }
            },
            midClick: true,
            removalDelay: 300
        });

});
```

And my HTML:

```
<a class="popup-content" href="#modal" data-effect="my-mfp-slide-bottom">Open popup link</a>

<div id="modal" class="zoom-anim-dialog mfp-hide">
<a href="http://example.com">This link does not work</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `onclick='window.open("https://example.com");'` 
to your anchor tag.So now your link will look like 
`<a href="http://example.com"                 onclick='window.open("https://example.com");'>This link does not work</a>`

Comment: Not a perfect solution as it has to launch a new window. So you now have two windows, the new window opening the target and the original window linking to the gallery item. But, it does work around the issue so thank you Santosh for your input.